# SetFilterWidgetType is not working in Grid.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to use Filters in Grid.MVC from this page to show proper filtering for text, Number, bool and Date.

https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Filtering&referringTitle=Client%20side%20%28javascript%29

I have problem to getting it correctly. When I add the line to add filter, the filter is not even open
That is the line:

```
columns.Add(model => model.NMLS).Titled("NMLS").Sortable(true).Filterable(true).SetFilterWidgetType("BooleanFilterWidget");
```

it is opening filter when I dont have this line :

```
 SetFilterWidgetType("BooleanFilterWidget");
```

but I need to use different filter to make it more frindly.(like , umbder. bool, date...)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SetFilterWidgetType("System.Boolean")
```

to make it work.

Grid.Mvc support several types of columns (specified in Add method):

```
System.String
System.Int32
System.Int64
System.Boolean
System.DateTime
System.Decimal
System.Byte
System.Double
System.Single
```